# How to search two driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text

Tags: python, selenium, automation, bots

I am trying to create an automated bot to purchase items from supreme python/selenium.

When I am on the products page and I use a `driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Flight Pant')` to find the product I want to buy, however I also want to select the colour of the product so I use a `driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Black')` but by doing this I am returned with the first Black product on the page instead of Flight pants that are Black. Any idea how I would achieve this goal?

here is the site link where I am try to achieve this,

http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/pants

Note - I am unable to use xpaths for this, as the products change on a weekly bases so I would be unable to get the xpath for the product before it goes live on the site.

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath, but the maneuver is slightly trickier. The XPath would be:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "Flight Pant")]/../following-sibling::p/a[contains(text(), "Black")]')
```

Assuming the structure of the page doesn't change on a weekly basis... To explain my XPath:

> `//*[contains(text(), "Flight Pant")]`

Select any node that contains the text "Flight Pant". These are all `<a>` tags.

> `/../following-sibling::p`

Notice how the DOM looks:

```
<h1>
  <a class="name-link" href="/shop/pants/dfkjdafkj">Flight Pant</a>
</h1>
<p>
  <a class="name-link" href="/shop/pants/pvfcp0txzy">Black</a>
</p>
```

So we need to go to the parent *and* find its sibling that is a `<p>` element.

> `/a[contains(text(), "Black")]`

Now go to the `<a>` tag that has the text Black.

The reason there's not really any other alternative to XPath is because there's no unique way to identify the desired element by any other means (tag name, class, link text, etc.)

Comment: Hi Mangohero1, 

I have tested the code you have provided and it works great for most items, however when testing it on the bags page to find a Shoulder Bag in Black and some other items on that page it doesn't always work I get the same issues with the accessory page and the hats page. 

Any idea why this is happening?

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appropriated, thanks again for the code.

Comment: Anytime :) link me to one of those pages and I'll see what could be the issue

Comment: Thank you for looking in to this :) here are the links,

http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/bags
http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/accessories
http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/hats

Comment: The bags page for me does not show a Shoulder Bag in black. For the other two, I'm not running into any problems.. It may be how you're putting the `text` part of the XPath. For example, on [hats](http://supremenewyork.com/shop/all/hats), if you wanted the Black Supreme®/The North Face® Mountain 6-Panel Hat, the text operator matches partial text as well. So just putting 6-Panel Hat would match it

Answer (score 0):

After finding elements by the link text "Flight pants" , iterate over each found result and extract its css color attributes. Its a **psuedo-code**. You have to fine tune the specific color extraction web elements.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text("Flight Pants")

for element in elements :
  if(element.get_css_value('color').lower() == "black")
    element.click()
    break
```

Comment: This would not suffice. All `elements` have a black color as their CSS value. You're calling the method on the link text color... all of which are black :P